# How to disable step-into debugging for a package?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, nuget-package

I've created a NuGet package and while testing it I found that whenever stepping into a method in the package Visual Studio shows the code, I would like it to not be the case.

The package has been built under a *Release* configuration.

What is needed in order to disable step-through the code of the package classes ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you publishing the PDB files with your NuGet package? If so, Visual Studio is doing the expected behaviour of allowing you to step in.

If you definitely want to include the PDB, you'll need to add the `[DebuggerStepThrough]` attribute to *every* class in your assembly.  This will however make debugging a nightmare for you, unless you use a `#if BLAH` hash-define condition to only do this in Release mode.

My suggestion would be to *not* include the PDBs in your NuGet package, then you don't need to amend your code at all.

Comment: Yup. No PDB = no lines of code, just method signatures.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`DebuggerHidden`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerhiddenattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute on your classes. The `DebuggerNonUserCode` and `DebuggerStepThrough` attributes would also work.

Comment: Okay but does that mean that I would have to decorate all the types in that package with that attribute ?